# Codeigniter email function and Justhost SMTP

Tags: codeigniter, smtp

I had somebody build me a site using PHP and Codeigniter framework.On the test server everything was working properly, but now, once the site is transfered on Justhost, email function doesnt work.At first i tought i didnt used the correct SMTP settings, but they are fine (support took a look).

Basically, owner can put his property on the site (like this:http://goo.gl/AZcrj), and when the visitor fills the contact form on the bottom, email is sent to owners email address, and the he can reply to the visitors email.

First time i used Justhost SMTP settings and tested it, email was sent.But from that point, till now, i always get an error when i try to send message via contact form.I even tried using Gmail SMTP settings, same thing happens :\

Here is the code, does anybody have any clue?
Btw, im a PHP rookie, so i dont know much, but i did my best to explain

```
public function send_mail($res)
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']    = 'sslsmtp.gmail.com'; --- i tried with ssl://smtp.gmail.com, same thing happens
    $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
    $config['smtp_user']    = 'email';
    $config['smtp_pass']    = 'password';


    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from($res['sender_email'], $res['sender_name']);
    $this->email->to($res['reciever']);
    $this->email->reply_to($res['sender_email'], $res['sender_name']);

    $this->email->subject('Email from site.');
    $this->email->message($res['message']);

    if($this->email->send()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    //configure mail agent...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems Justhost blocks outgoing ports for shared IPs. I was having the same issue and came across this link (https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/405) while searching for an answer.

From the above link:

> Outgoing Ports Are Blocked
>
> Just Host restricts port access as a result of the shared hosting
>   environment. In this environment, every account on a server shares a
>   single IP address. As a result, most ports are blocked because no
>   single account is assigned the IP address for the box.
>
> To gain access to these ports, it is necessary to lease a dedicated IP
>   address through Just Host.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it is necessary to add the essential parts of the answer here also. Link only answers would become invalid if the linked page becomes inactive.